# Use filter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="main">
    <a title="here" href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a class="click" href="#">check site</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <a title="here" href="http://stackoverflow">stackoverflow</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a class="click" href="#">check site</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <a title="here" href="http://cnn.com">cnn.com</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a title="sss" href="www.sss.com">sss</a>
    <a class="click" href="#">check site</a>
</div>
```

i wrote:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().filter("[title=here]").attr('href'));
})
```

but this show me undefined. How can i get current site from current DIV?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/uB4ez/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `filter` method filters out specific items from a result, you want to use the `find` method to find children of the element in the result:

```
alert($(this).parent().find("[title=here]").attr('href'));
```

The `filter` method would be used if you have all the childred and want to keep a specific one. Example:

```
alert($(this).parent().children().filter("[title=here]").attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`.filter()` doesn't get child nodes.

If you want to look at only the next level of children nodes, use `.children("[title=here]")`.

To search all descendant nodes, use `.find("[title=here]")`